# What is the fastest cache for small and rarely changing data to use with Django?

Tags: php, python, django, caching

I am in a process of switching from PHP to Python + Django and looking for equivalent of PHP's "Array cache".

For small data sets from DB like "categories" that was changing very rarely but accessed very often i was using array cache.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/09/cache-performance-comparison/

Concept of it was to generate PHP source with the tree of categories and when the opcode was turned on it was working like embedding data into application sources. It was the fastest imaginable cache, very helpful for large load.

Django manual(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/) states:

> By far the fastest, most efficient type of cache available to Django, Memcached..

So the questions are:

- Would generating a .py file with python dictionaries/lists made any sense?
- Will this be faster than Memcached? If not why?
- Are there any known implementations of this?
- Does Python have anything like var_export() function from PHP?

EDIT:

As pointed in an answer i can use repr() and this can be benchmarked easily so i have created a simple benchmark:

https://github.com/fsw/pythonCachesBenchmark

output of this on my local machine was:

```
FIRST RUN
get_categories_from_db
6.57282209396
get_categories_from_memcached
(SET CACHE IN 0.000940)
4.88948512077
get_categories_from_pickledfile
(SET CACHE IN 0.000917)
2.87856888771
get_categories_from_pythonsrc
(SET CACHE IN 0.000489)
0.0930788516998
SECOND RUN
get_categories_from_db
6.63035202026
get_categories_from_memcached
4.60877108574
get_categories_from_pickledfile
2.87137699127
get_categories_from_pythonsrc
0.0903170108795
```

get_categories_from_pythonsrc is simple implementation of PHP's arraycache i was talking about:

```
def get_categories_from_pythonsrc():
    if not os.path.exists('catcache.py'):
        start = time.time()
        f = open( 'catcache.py', 'wb' )
        categories = get_categories_from_db()
        f.write('x = ' + repr(categories))
        f.close()
        print '(SET CACHE IN %f)' % (time.time() - start)
    import catcache
    return catcache.x
```

this is my simple pickledfile cache implementation:

```
def get_categories_from_pickledfile():
    path = 'catcache.p'
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        start = time.time()
        pickle.dump( get_categories_from_db(), open( path, 'wb' ) )
        print '(SET CACHE IN %f)' % (time.time() - start)
    return pickle.load(open( path, 'rb' ));
```

complete source:

https://github.com/fsw/pythonCachesBenchmark/blob/master/test.py

I will later add "Django's low-level cache APIs" to this benchmark to see what they are about.

So as my intuition suggested caching dictionary in a python .py file is the fastest way i could get (over 30 times faster than cPickle + file)

As said i am new to Python so probably i am missing something here?

If not: why isn't this solution widely used?

Comment: Python has [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), which can serialize most Python objects. Although if you want to see which is faster, I don't think it'd be hard to setup a simple test case.

Comment: Would something like mongodb.org perhaps work? A non-relational db you can create keys relevant to whatever needs to be cached.

Comment: As @denmat said, I would do NoSql, I use Redis.

Comment: thanks @Blender this might solve my problem. I use NoSql's for stuff but i guess they still require some connection and for sure embedding data in source would be faster. I bet there is a faster way.

Comment: That Django cache documentation also covers the low level Django caching layer (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-low-level-cache-api) which can create an in memory cache of arbitrary key value pairs.

Comment: @FraserGraham ok i see. i misunderstood and thought this memcached bit is about the low level cache api. I will add Django caches to my benchmark then.

Answer (score 1):

Python has several solutions that may work here:

- Memcached (as you already know),
- pickle (as Blender mentioned) - which of course can be used with eg. Memcached,
- several other caching (eg. for local memory) & serialization (eg. `simplejson`) solutions,

In general `pickle` is very fast (use `cPickle` if you need more speed) and in Python you do not need anything like `var_export()` (although you can use `repr()` on variables to have their valid literal, if they are of one of primitive types). `pickle` in Python is more similar to `serialize` in PHP.

Your question is not very specific, but the above should give you some insight. Also you need to take into account that PHP and Python have different philosophies, so solutions to the same problems may look differently. In this specific case `pickle` module should solve your issues.

Comment: It gave me some insight indeed. thanks. Pickle looks promising. I will try to implement what i was talking about, do some benchmarking, and get back here.

Comment: I have added benchmark to my question. maybe it will help showing my problem. I understand Python and PHP differs but if they are used in an MVC framework then i guess caching problem appears in both.

Answer (score 1):

There is one other approach. You could use some **ASYNC server like gevent** and have live objects in some global namespace.
I do not know how familiar you are with such workflow, it is different from apache/php "each request starts bare".

Basically, you load your application, and use it to serve requests. It is alive all time and is sleeping if there are no requests. Once you load "categories" from database, store them in global variable or some module.

Let's say that you launch WSGI instance and give it name app. Afterwards, you can just have dictionary in that app and store cache there.
So no serialization, network protocols, all data is directly available in RAM.

EDIT1: DO NOT USE globals often, this is just one of very rare cases where it is OK to store something in `global` namespace (in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am familiar with the concept (my first steps in web programming were JAVA servlets. i guess the concept is similar?). Did not realize this approach can be used together with Django. WSGI is definitely something for me to read about.

Comment: Yeah, concept is similar, difference is that both 'servlet' and 'request' are in same app. For a start, you might try using flask o werkzeug with gevent just to get first impression, and then move to Django. (PS. I have used Django only briefly)